# How do I get errors only for the files that error out

Tags: vba, ms-access, text-files

At my company we need to convert a lot of text files each month to excel and some of the columns we need to change the data types of the columns.  They used to convert all of them manually which was very time consuming.  I created an access program that they can do it in much easier. They just hit  a button and it transfers them, with a running list of all the files converted.  Some of the files will change here and there, so when running the program I have another list that is supposed to show all the files that cause an error.  Unfortunately, what it does, at the moment, once it receives the error from one file - every file after that also says there is an error.  So if there are 100 files witch file 5 and 25 as errors, it would still show all files from 5 to 100 are errors.  Here is the code I am using:

```
    Public Sub ImportTextFile(ByVal xl As Excel.Application, ByVal strFileName As String, ByVal iNumOfCols As Integer, Optional aDataTypes As Variant = Nothing)

    On Error GoTo Sub_Err
    Dim sPathAndFile As String: sPathAndFile = cPath & strFileName
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Add
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
    With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & sPathAndFile & ".txt", Destination:=ws.Range("$A$1"))
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = False
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = GetColumnDataTypes(iNumOfCols, aDataTypes)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Call SaveFile(wb, sPathAndFile)
    
    Forms("Dashboard").lbCompleted.AddItem strFileName
    Forms("Dashboard").lbCompleted.Selected(Forms("Dashboard").lbCompleted.ListCount - 1) = True
    
Sub_End:
    Set wb = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
    Err.Clear
    Exit Sub
Sub_Err:
    'MsgBox Err.Description
    Forms("Dashboard").lbError.AddItem strFileName
    Resume Sub_End
    
End Sub
```

and then each file calls back like this:

```
Call ImportTextFile(xl, "DGXC094P", 11)
Call ImportTextFile(xl, "DGAC081", 18, Array(, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 2))
```

I tried clearing the error but it doesn't clear.  What am I doing wrong?  How can I get it to show only the files that have errors?

Comment: If one file errors is the type of error on the next file the same?  What type of error message are you getting?

Comment: If there is error, does an instance of Excel persist in Task Manager? Since you can't run the SaveFile() line, probably need to do something else to clear the instance - like Close and Quit.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the Sub to import the Textfile: Make it a function. Then you are able to give a callback if there was an error or not. Like this:

```
Public Function ImportTextFile(ByVal xl As Excel.Application, ByVal strFileName As String, ByVal iNumOfCols As Integer, Optional aDataTypes As Variant = Nothing) as string

On Error GoTo ErrorHandling
Dim sPathAndFile As String: sPathAndFile = cPath & strFileName
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Add
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & sPathAndFile & ".txt", Destination:=ws.Range("$A$1"))
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = False
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = GetColumnDataTypes(iNumOfCols, aDataTypes)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
Call SaveFile(wb, sPathAndFile)

Forms("Dashboard").lbCompleted.AddItem strFileName
Forms("Dashboard").lbCompleted.Selected(Forms("Dashboard").lbCompleted.ListCount - 1) = True

Set wb = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing
ImportTextFile = "ok"
Exit Function

ErrorHandling:
Set wb = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing
ImportTextFile = Err.Description

End Function
```

Your procedure to call the function should look like this:

```
Dim ImportResult as string

ImportResult = ImportTextFile(xl, "DGAC081", 18, Array(, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 2))

'Case Import Error
If ImportResult <> "ok" then
    MsgBox (ImportResult)
    Forms("Dashboard").lbError.AddItem strFileName
end if

'Case Import OK
If ImportResult = "ok" then
    'What you want
end if
```

When using a function instead of a sub you will be able to treat each import individually.

Comment: The function isn't raising an error when it should.  If the exact same code is in a sub, it will  raise but it won't raise the error when in the function.  I have never seen this.

Comment: If there is no error risen at all: What happens if you run the function ImportTextFile in debug mode step by step?
Furthermore you can declare the function ImportTextFile "as string" and then submit the error-message as the result of this function. I made changes in the code above to achieve that. I also added a MsgBox to make clear where the error message is.